# outputting (to display) a string from Javascript or Jquery to a line in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying many different ways of outputting a concatenated string (including playing around with other examples found on stackover flow of having text fields in html and then using javascript for concatenating them)
as a line in html.
Whatever example I try and play around with though, I do not seem to know how to display the string (have tried various output methods from w3schools such as window.alert(); etc)
so my latest try is the code below found on https://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-append-add-text-to-element/

What am I missing when I paste this text into an html doc and open it locally in my browser (chrome and firefox) for making it append the text?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 5px 0pt; padding: 5px;">Example div</div>
<form>
    <div><textarea class="example-default-value" id="example-textarea" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>
    <div><input type="button" value="Append" onclick="example_append()" /></div>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
$('.example-default-value').each(function() {
    var default_value = this.value;
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if(this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if(this.value == '') {
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});
function example_append() {
    $('#example').append($('#example-textarea').val());
}
</script>
```

Thank you so so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add jQuery, then it works.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 5px 0pt; padding: 5px;">Example div</div>
<form>
    <div><textarea class="example-default-value" id="example-textarea" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>
    <div><input type="button" value="Append" onclick="example_append()" /></div>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
$('.example-default-value').each(function() {
    var default_value = this.value;
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if(this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if(this.value == '') {
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});
function example_append() {
    $('#example').append($('#example-textarea').val());
}
</script>
```

For your information, in case you're new to JavaScript: if you see `$` in the script, it is very likely jQuery :) So if it is not already included, add it to your page.

Comment: Thank you so so much; it's so embarrassing, but now I'm aware of something else I need to look out for! That's probably also why my javascript files weren't working either; I'm new to coding completely, but this has been driving me crazy since I first looked at examples like this to play around with last year!  Have a lovely day!

Comment: Glad it helped :) Please mark the answer as accepted so that it can help the rest of the community when they'll get back here! And happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

I changed some codes and updating here.. Usually I prefer to declare `click event in JQuery` instead of using `onClick=functionName();`

So I changed your HTML (Just removed the onClick=** ) and deleted the function also and declare the click event  and then called the `.append()`..

```js
$('.example-default-value').each(function() {
    var default_value = this.value;
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if(this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if(this.value == '') {
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});
$('#myBtn').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#example').append($('#example-textarea').val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 5px 0pt; padding: 5px;">Example div</div>
<form>
    <div><textarea class="example-default-value" id="example-textarea" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>
    <div><input id="myBtn" type="button" value="Append" /></div>
</form>
```

Assuming that you linked JQuery in your code already. If not then add the Jquery in your file by putting this line

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`